# Jackson 2.5+: what JsonSerializer methods must be overridden by wrapping JsonSerializer returned from BeanSerializerModifier.modifySerializer(...)?

Tags: jackson

Using Jackson 2.5+, what `JsonSerializer` methods must be overridden by a wrapping `JsonSerializer` returned from:

```
BeanSerializerModifier.modifySerializer(SerializationConfig sc, BeanDescription bd, JsonSerializer<?> js)
```

I'm definitely overriding `serialize(...)`, because I'm filtering out some objects from being serialized based on the values of their properties in that override.  Otherwise, if the object isn't filtered out by its property values, I serialize normally by calling `js.serialize(...)`, where `js` is the `JsonSerializer` that was passed as an argument to `modifySerializer`.

But I'm not sure if I should also override any of the following other `JsonSerializer` methods:

1. `getDelegatee()`
2. `replaceDelegatee(...)`
3. `isUnwrappingSerializer()`
4. `unwrappingSerializer(...)`
5. `handledType()`
6. `usesObjectId()`
7. `isEmpty(T)`
8. `isEmpty(SerializerProvider, T)`
9. `acceptJsonFormatVisitor(...)`
10. `serializeWithType(...)`

e.g., Should `getDelegatee()` return `js`?

Why would I want to allow `replaceDelegatee(...)` to replace `js` as the delegatee?  If I should allow this, then I'd have to save `js` to a field so I could replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my other answer, some of those you do want to (re)define, others not. (1), (8), (9) and (10) do make sense; (7) is deprecated and not needed any more. (5) should be defined by base class (at least if extending `StdSerailizer`), if not defined, should be defined mostly because it is used by some error reporting.

(3) and (4) are things you may want to support, if you want `@JsonUnwrapped` to be implemented for the type. If you are delegating to a standard POJO serializer, this is probably true. If not implemented, `@JsonUnwrapped` will basically have no effect on properties with your custom serializer.

(6) applies similarly for `@JsonIdentityInfo`; but note that object identity may be tricky to handle with delegation model.

As to delegatee replacement... I would not worry about that one. I think it was added speculatively, and is not actually used by the framework.